# url validator is not working javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript function that will validate a url

```
function isValidUrl(textval){
var urlregex = new RegExp("^(http|https|ftp)\://([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+(\:[a-zA-Z0-9\.&amp;%\$\-]+)*@)*((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[0-9])|([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.(com|edu|gov|int|mil|net|org|biz|arpa|info|name|pro|aero|coop|museum|[a-zA-Z]{2}))(\:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9\.\,\?\'\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~_\-]+))*$");
      return urlregex.test(textval);
}
```

but this seems not to work, when I enter `http://asdf` only.
any Ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: I think that is because it only validates domains.

Comment: Uhm... the function does not accept any argument. Where does `textval` come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function isValidUrl(inputurl){
return /^(https?|ftp):\/\/(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?(((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?)(:\d*)?)(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)?(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(\#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?$/i.test(inputurl);
}
```

works also like on the jquery validator.
get this from : http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js

Comment: I had an issue with this regexp because it doesn't allow pipe characters. Pipe characters are technically not allowed, but the real world is different...

Answer (score 1):

The question has been tagged with jquery.  If you're using jquery, why not just use the [validator plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this RegEx:

```
   /(((f|ht){1}tp|tps:\/\/)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]+)/
```

[Example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Shaz/ee6xh/):

```
function validUrl(str) {
    return str.test(/(((f|ht){1}tp|tps:\/\/)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]+)/);
}

alert(validUrl("http://www.google.com")); // true
alert(validUrl("https://www.google.com")); // true
alert(validUrl("ftp://www.google.com")); // true
alert(validUrl("ftps://www.google.com")); // true
alert(validUrl("yoda://I.speak.like")); // false
```

Comment: this doesnt work. Is it also possible if I entered www.google.com or google.com this should also accepted?